# Formly does not show up in ng-dialog

Tags: angular-formly

I use the Mean-Stack SPA start from scotch.io.
For dialogs I use ng-dialog.
For forms I want to use angular-formly.
I call in the MainCtrl ng-dialog.open to own searchdialog.html.
In the searchdialog.html I want replace a form with angular-formly.

A normal form shows up in the dialog, the formly-coded part does not show up, only the submit-button.

The code is here [JS BIN link](http://jsbin.com/hoqiqobodu/edit?html,js,output)

Why the formly-form does not show up, but normal forms show up?

EDIT: I added my complete testcode here

[GithubCode](https://github.com/maximizeyourefficiency/docma)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that you're not including the angular-formly library  (or even angular) on the page. You'll need to do that first. Also, you're not depending on the angular-formly module `'formly'` in your module definition.

If you're not already familiar with how to depend on third-party modules in your angular code, I recommend you read the documentation on [Angular modules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module). Then, follow the [getting started instructions](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs) on the angular-formly docs. Then take a look at [the examples](http://angular-formly.com/) from the angular-formly website. You'll notice that they all include the angular-formly library as script tags. If you'll be using normal script tags, you'll want to download those dependencies and add them to your project.

Good luck!

Comment: it is included, I get no error or missing module. the module is loaded in my app.js like all the other modules.

Comment: i only added the code which directly touches formly. All other files like Index.html, app.js, appRoutes are not on jsbin...

Comment: Please see the mainpost. I added my whole code to github.

Comment: When I run your code locally, I get the errror: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'StraDocMaApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.` seems like that might be related...

Comment: sorry, its updated pls update your code. I made some changes till data privacy

Comment: Updating `StraDocMaApp` [here](https://github.com/maximizeyourefficiency/docma/blob/15314fdd3136010ff4ec80ad11cfdc43a0c3fbf1/public/js/scripts/kostenstellen.js#L6) to `DocMaApp` fixes that bug. Investigating the rest of the problem... Please one sec.

Comment: From the look of it, the `SearchCtrl` is not hooking up to the dialog properly. Definitely not a formly issue. If you try to bind anything else, you'll see that it doesn't have any of the right properties...

Comment: thank you, yesterday I spent 3 hours on the same, but I can't find the issue. I will take more hours to solve it...

Comment: Can you try it with the module "ng-dialog" -> https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog IMHO it does not work together. Other actions in the SearchCtrl work fine, except formly...